# Angular - checking for new data and applying a custom class or function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-resource

I have a very simple poller that fetches new data every 4000ms.

What I'm trying to achieve is that if new data is different from the old one, only this new data should be pushed to DOM and for example apply a class to it with an animation and keep the old data without any animation.

Currently, it replaces all the data in the DOM. I tried to use `$watch` which should check only for new value(element), but that doesn't work.

Is there a way for comparing old data with new and applying a custom function/class to only those new data maybe using a directive?

code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngResource','emguo.poller']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,poller, myData) {
  var poller;
  poller = poller.get (myData, {delay: 4000,smart: true});

  poller.promise.then (null, null, function (data) {
        $scope.items = data.records;
  });
})
.factory('myData', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('data.json',{}, {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}});
}).directive('myData', function() {
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.myData, function(val, oldVal) {
                  if(val !=oldVal){
                    console.log(element)
                  }
                });
            }
        }
});
```

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/qRXgPqrd7nvmdf9ciJRC?p=preview)

Many thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a directive this, you can just check when fetching the data whether the record exists in `$scope.items` already, and if it doesn't, you can push the fetched record to it. Example plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/KwqP6AHINGQ9IlOz5vAv?p=preview

Comment: That's great. But what about deleting data. For instance the new array(object) doesn't include the old data(object) anymore but the old data will still be present in DOM?

Comment: We're never deleting the old `$scope.items`, we're just adding to it, so the old data will be there, too.

Comment: Sure, but what about splicing the `$scope.items` something like `$scope.items.splice(record)` but it doesn't work. The same principle you did with adding the data, now I need to splice them if the new data.json doesn't have those data anymore. Can you please help?